# Convert a string to another one in java

Tags: java, string, replace

How do I convert `#title` to `<h1>title</h1>` in java? I'm trying to create an algorithm to convert markdown format to html format.

Comment: what did you try? the Q is unclear...

Comment: You can read the code of http://code.google.com/p/markdownj/

Comment: Why won't you use some existing Markdown parser?

Comment: I can't use a markdown parser. It's for my programming class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to create markdown algorithm look for regular expression.

```
String noHtml = "#title1";
String html = noHtml.replaceAll("#(.+)", "<h1>$1</h1>");
```

answer to comment - more about character classes [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html):

```
String noHtml = "#title1";
String html = noHtml.replaceAll("#([a-zA-Z]+)", "<h1>$1</h1>");
```

Comment: wow thanks a lot, and how do I make #(followed by a space) not turn into <h1> </h1> ?

Comment: `noHtml.replaceAll("#([^\\s]+)", "<h1>$1</h1>");`

Answer (score 1):

Say that you used a hash at the *beginning* and the *end* of the marked word(s), you could use a method like this which would do all of them in a String.

```
private String replaceTitles(String entry) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("#(.*?)#").matcher(entry);
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(entry.length());
    while (m.find()) {

        String text = m.group(1);
        StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
        b.append("<h1>").append(text).append("</h1>");

        m.appendReplacement(buf, Matcher.quoteReplacement(b.toString()));
    }
    m.appendTail(buf);
    return buf.toString();
}
```

If you called

```
replaceTitles("#My Title One!# non title text, #One more#")
```

it would return

```
"<h1>My Title One!</h1> non title text, <h1>One more</h1>"
```

Comment: why would you change the question to suit your answer. OP asked specifically about one #. And instead of such a long code, Jakub's answer looks perfect.

Comment: Totally agreed. But I was trying to make the OP think how it could help to be extended. What if they wanted to have a String with some h1 and some normal text in it? Or multiple h1 text in a given String?

Comment: Also, this method could be slightly changed and you could process a given String, and markup all of the bold text, italic text, different title size etc.

Comment: your code is not wrong, but generally there will be only 1 marker and not 2 at both the ends, the grouping will automatically handle them. As you say your method can be changed, same thing can be applied to Jakub's answer. The point is to keep the code simple and stupid. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  String inString = "#title";
  String outString = "<h1>"+inString.substring(1)+"</h1>";
```

or

```
  String outString = "<h1>"+"#title".substring(1)+"</h1>";
```