# markdown algorithm java; converter problems

Tags: java, markdown

```
public class Md2html {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

       String stringToConvert = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
       System.out.println(convert(stringToConvert));

    }

    public static String convert(String str) {

         if (str.equals("# "))
             System.out.println(" ");

         Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(#+[^#]+)");
         Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

         while (matcher.find()) {
             String str1 = matcher.group(1);
             if(str1.replaceFirst("#+", "").length() == 0 ||
                str1.replaceFirst("#+", "").matches("[\\s]+")) 
                      continue;
             int n = str1.length() - str1.replaceFirst("#+", "").length();
             System.out.println("<h" + n + ">" + str1.substring(n) + 
                                "</h" + n + ">");

             double carac;
             carac = str.charAt(0);
             if(carac>65 & carac <=90) {
                  System.out.print("<p>");
                  System.out.println(str);
                  System.out.println("<p>");
             }
        }

        return ("");
    }     
}
```

Ok, so now I have an algorithm that converts # to < h1> < h2> depending on the number of #...I'm now trying to add < p> at the beginning of a paragraph and < /p> at the end of it. For some reason,the second part of the converter, which is supposed to add < p> at the beginning and < /p> at the end of a paragraph doesnt seem to work (it's the code starting with double carac). Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong???

Comment: `isn't working` -> There are infinite definitions of not working. Which one is in your case?

Comment: the second part of the converter, which is supposed to add < p> at the beginning and < /p> at the end of a paragraph doesnt seem to work. it's the code starting with double carac

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002007/mini-homemade-markdown-processor-in-java

Comment: @Arn0ld_t you have asked the same question many times and you have accepted the answers and your questions have been marked as closed, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001259/convert-a-string-to-another-one-in-java

Comment: Again you said the same thing.. What do you mean by `doesn't work`?? Can you post expected output and actual output?

Comment: ok ok
so ##Decibel should give < p> < h2> Decibel < /h2> < /p> but instead it returns < h2> Decibel < /h2>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing two opening tags for a paragraph if the string starts with an uppercase letter and no closing tag. Replace

```
System.out.print("<p>");
System.out.println(str);
System.out.println("<p>");
```

with

```
System.out.print("<p>");
System.out.println(str);
System.out.println("</p>"); //<--here
```

Also, you should use a logical AND `&&` instead of a bitwise AND `&` for boolean operations.

Also, [`String#charAt(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) returns a `char`, not a `double`. You are declaring `carac` as a `double`. Declare as a `char` instead.

Comment: thank you. didn't see that one. But I'm also having a problem with the first part of the code:
    double carac;
    carac = str.charAt(0);
    if(carac>65 & carac <=90){